# bootstrap pictures overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to Html & Css. I'm trying to make a portfolio site as an exercise for myself. However, when I try to put multiple pictures next to eachother, sort of like a gallery. My pictures start to overlap eachother. I have tried to find a solution for a few hours now. But nothing seems to work.

Does any of you guys have a suggestion that might lead to a solution?
Thanks in advance!!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmIwb.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0>

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <title>Noah Wallaart</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="header">  
        <div class="navbar navbar-default"> 
           <div class="container">

            </div>  
        </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">     
                      <h1>Noah Wallaart</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">    
                </div>      
         </div>  
     </div>
</div>     

<section>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
       </div>

    </div>

</section>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo, 'col-md-' instead of 'col-md-3' on the first image column

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my questions, it did fix something. But it still overlaps eachother. I provided a picture so u can see what it looks like. Thanks in advance. https://imgur.com/5HcQXEo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .col-md-3{
        margin: 10px;
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Andrew. However it just made the 4th picture jump over to te next row. And the 3 pictures above just kept overlapping eachother.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. Add the class "responsive" to the images so:  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG" class = "img-responsive"></div>

Comment: Or make the images smaller until they all fit on the same line

Comment: This helped a lot. They are kept from overlapping now. But this prevents me from choosing the right image size for my size right? And 2 other things if you dont mind. https://imgur.com/w3tVncu . As you can see, the pictures are practicly centered in the site. I would like them to be more divided among the width of the screen. I tried to achieve that by giving the pictures a Left/right margin. But neither worked. And then when I scale the website down, the Pictures are put on top of eachother without any space between. How would I solve both of these problems. Thanks in advance! Gr. Noah

Comment: To have them more divided on the screen, change the container class to "container-fluid", then to each column you have, change each one to "col-lg-3" if you still want 4 images on a line, or "col-lg-6" if you want 2 on a line.

Comment: The images are stacked due to Bootstrap, bootstrap is a responsive framework so they automatically stack. Changing the columns should do this as I mentioned in the previous post :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

to

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
           <div class="col-md-3"><img src="image/background.JPG"></div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

You missed off the 3, which means the medium columns won't add up to the correct 12 so there will be some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've used your code and it seems like it's due to the size of the images. Trying specifying the images with the same width on each one.